# Finding last word in tweepy tweet response python

Tags: python, twitter

I am receiving a stream of tweets with python and would like to extract the last word or know where to reference it.

for example in

> NC don’t like working together www.linktowtweet.org

get back

```
 together
```

Comment: What have you tried ? Use str.split() then use `import re` to find if it's a link or no.

Comment: Ah, so i could just split the string, and get the next to last split element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with tweepy, so I am presuming you have the data in a python string, so maybe there is a better answer.

However, given a string in python, it simple to extract the last word.

**Solution 1**

Use `str.rfind(' ')`. The idea here is to find the space, preceding the last word. Here is an example.

```
text = "NC don’t like working together"
text = text.rstrip() # To any spaces at the end, that would otherwise confuse the algorithm.
last_word = text[text.rfind(' ')+1:] # Output every character *after* the space.
print(last_word)
```

Note: If a string is given with no words, `last_word` will be a blank string.

Now this presumes that all of the words are separated by spaces. To handle newlines and spaces, use `str.replace` to turn them into strings. Whitespaces in python are `\t\n\x0b\x0c\r`, but I presume only newlines and tabs will be found in twitter messages.

Also see: [`string.whitespace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.whitespace)

So a complete example (wrapped as a function) would be

```
def last_word(text):
    text = text.replace('\n', ' ') # Replace newlines with spaces.
    text = text.replace('\t', ' ') # Replace tabs with spaces.
    text = text.rstrip(' ') # Remove trailing spaces.
    return text[text.rfind(' ')+1:]

print(last_word("NC don’t like working together")) # Outputs "together".
```

This may still be the best situation for basic parsing. There is something better for larger problems.

**Solution 2**

Regular Expressions

These are a way to handle strings in python, that is a lot more flexible. REGEX, as they are often called, use there own language to specify a portion of text.

For example, `.*\s(\S+)` specifies the last word in a string.

Here is it again with a longer explanation.

```
.*               # Match as many characters as possible.
\s               # Until a whitespace ("\t\n\x0b\x0c\r ")
(                # Remember the next section for the answer.
\S+              # Match a ~word~ (not whitespace) as possible.
)                # End saved section.
```

So then, in python you would use this as follows.

```
import re # Import the REGEX library.

# Compile the code, (DOTALL makes . match \n).
LAST_WORD_PATTERN = re.compile(r".*\s(\S+)", re.DOTALL) 

def last_word(text):
    m = LAST_WORD_PATTERN.match(text)
    if not m: # If there was not a last word to this text.
        return ''
    return m.group(1) # Otherwise return the last word.

print(last_word("NC don’t like working together")) # Outputs "together".
```

Now, even though this method is a lot less obvious, it has a couple of advantages. First off, it is a lot more customizable. If you wanted to match the final word, but not links, the regex `r".*\s([^.:\s]+(?!\.\S|://))\b"` would match the last word, but ignore a link if that was the last thing.

Example:

```
import re # Import the REGEX library.

# Compile the code, (DOTALL makes . match \n).
LAST_WORD_PATTERN = re.compile(r".*\s([^.:\s]+(?!\.\S|://))\b", re.DOTALL)

def last_word(text):
    m = LAST_WORD_PATTERN.match(text)
    if not m: # If there was not a last word to this text.
        return ''
    return m.group(1) # Otherwise return the last word.

print(last_word("NC don’t like working together www.linktowtweet.org")) # Outputs "together".
```

The second advantage to this method is speed.

As you can [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3VTBbtpAEL37K6bOYb1AnUa9VEhVhZoeKqEQAVIPmFoGBrzC9lq7Q0ylHvob/b3@CN1dAzGlaZSq7aFcjMfz3sx73ufyE6WyeLnbibyUioBEjoI87wJGpESxAkJNnkbalLGuK69B@b7vLXAJWaIprqRaBIRb4l0PzM/@NU32Eioss2SOAYsK1gEGjMMFDOsiFFhlokANlaAUdGlqOvwFBZ1TUDJ7DG63LoMjLpd3BqYSkVktTZQyIlXhUJMauhTFwiHbV92pZ0XvnVC4wu3BiL1zCr1@bzSOPwyG1/Ftbzx@N7yxLRjOZV6KDAPlh61IB9Gozf2OfXA9GPf6ff6wlbkhOCMN84Tmad3musQSCkmQd43A90ugFBVClWhXTRwzWGYgaR4KXRvjoA3djDVdyMOVkpsyuLKuDSxlJTQePUrxnjY8cybeqEz/rj2Tj2E30tN28OZZFEajz93LS86j2X/omI1WfFRhFmf3kvybt7CQxbcvXwkysUaLW7s8yhVacp8zzytNICk45bHjb23dzZwnWQYzPCQZzew9yh@be5cBUvVR97mHW5wHzbTzfTfeJdmPg5qTrEcSSuXSZebKDZUbAlOu0sRcrfBNtjCrmAXqj4x5K6IIJuy5Nrluzuw81YgpP4hiLdZ69eKwtGIHjUMX2GYA2YlYd2z/rVY38m9LfShMP1HvQsu94zr2/olnEqqqCs13dU2yogqRQqlW9qD@eV8bjCcbc/6I405mB05AU77bfQc) here, the regex approach is almost as fast as the string manipulation, if not faster in some cases. (I actually found that regex execute .2 usec faster on my machine that in the demo.)

Either way, the regex execution is extremely fast, even in the simple case, and there is no question that the regex is faster then any more complex string algorithm implemented in python. So using the regex can also speed up the code.

---

**EDIT**
Changed the url avoiding regex from

```
re.compile(r".*\s([^.\s]+(?!\.\S))\b", re.DOTALL)
```

to

```
re.compile(r".*\s([^.:\s]+(?!\.\S|://))\b", re.DOTALL)
```

So that calling `last_word("NC don’t like working together http://www.linktowtweet.org")` returns `together` and not `http://`.

To so how this regex works, look at https://regex101.com/r/sdwpqB/2.

Comment: This is an amazing answer with great explanations, thank you so much, I am sure this will work

Answer (score 0):

Simple, so if your text is:

```
text = "NC don’t like working together www.linktowtweet.org"
text = re.sub(r'https?:\/\/.*[\r\n]*', '', text, flags=re.MULTILINE) #to remove any URL
text = text.split() #splits sentence into words with delimiter=" "
last_word = text[-1]
```

So there you go!! Now you'll get the last word "together".

Comment: Actually, this solution does not work for me. I get "www.linktowtweet.org" as the output. It seems the regex presumes all urls will start with "http" and fails if they don't. I do realize I do need to modify my code to handle the http case.